# Large co-H-spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm searching for examples of co-H-spaces that are not suspensions and that do not admit a finite cone decomposition with respect to the collection of finite type wedges of spheres.

We have many examples of co-H-spaces which are not suspensions - the most accessible of these examples are finite complexes, hence do admit finite cone decompositions in the aforementioned sense. On the other hand $\Sigma K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ is a co-H-space that does not admit a finite (spherical) cone decomposition, but is obviously a suspension...

Comment: If X is a d-dimensional finite example, what about $X \vee \Sigma K(\Bbb Z,N)$ for $N \gg d$? Does your proof that this is not a suspension still go through?

Comment: @TylerLawson - this does seem to be an example of the type of space I'm describing, but isn't quite horrible enough to test my hypothesis (which I'll avoid detailing here as it's pretty far afield); I've developed methods to handle spaces that decompose into wedges with "nice" summands.


I'll try and requantify in a coherent way just how terrible the spaces I'm searching for should be.